# How to Login Facebook when I have the access token ?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, token, access-token

I've been looking for a way to access FB when I already have 
the access token in my hand (:)) but I can't find one.

I've tried to login like this :

```
 this.NewLogin = function (FbToken, CallBackFunc) {

         window.location = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?" + FbToken;
         // do something with CallBackFunc
         // ...
    };
```

But it doesn't work.

How do I login with a token then ?

Comment: _“How do I login with a token then ?”_ - you don’t. Tokens are for authentication against the APIs, not to perform a user login against the front end.

Comment: @CBroe : OK then , how do I authenticate once I have the Token ?

Comment: If you need to make an API request - then you simply supply the token while doing so. (And if you mean something else, then please explain what that is in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

An access token is already the response you get from logging in into an app. You should be able to use it directly to query the API.

> When someone connects with an app using Facebook Login and approves the request for permissions, the app obtains an access token that provides temporary, secure access to Facebook APIs.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

If what you are trying to do is to authenticate to the FB website using the access token, that is not possible. An access token gives access to a limited set of data that the user agreed to share with the app.